# JWSC for weblogic 12c with Maven

Tags: web-services, maven, weblogic, weblogic12c

We are in the process of upgrading from Weblogic 10g to 12c.  A portion of our code base is webservices so we were using `weblogic-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <contextPath>ws</contextPath>
        <keepGenerated>true</keepGenerated>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jwsc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
            <version>${weblogic.version}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${bea.lib}/weblogic.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The build error I see is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:jwsc (default) on project webService: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:jwsc failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6 in http://ccicusbuild1/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Deeper inspection shows that the plugin has a dependency on `weblogic:weblogic:10.3.6` and `weblogic:webservices:10.3.6`.  As shown in the previous code, I can override `weblogic:weblogic:10.3.6` with `weblogic:weblogic:12.1.1`.  The problem is `webservices.jar` is no longer apart of weblogic 12c, so I have nothing to override the dependency with, nor can I exclude it.

The page for `weblogic-maven-plugin` (http://mojo.codehaus.org/weblogic-maven-plugin/) mentions support for 12c, but doesn't give any details.

The goal is to be able to run JWSC through maven.  Is there a tweak to the plugin configuration that I can do to make it work, or is there another plugin, or do I need to bite the bullet and run the code with the ant plugin?

Comment: What happens if you exclude the webservices jar?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of excluding it.  You can exclude dependencies of dependencies (transitive dependencies), but not dependencies of plugins.

Comment: Did you try wls-maven-plugin as mentioned here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/maven.htm

Comment: Agreed on the exclustions: See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2163

Comment: I saw `wls-maven-plugin`, but I didn't see anything in the docs about JWSC.  It appeared to be geared more towards deployment and server maintenance.  Perhaps, I just missed it, I'll check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the eventual solution we used.  If some one else has something better, please post it.

*plugins portion of pom.xml*

```
<plugins>
    <!--
        Below contains a work around to build web services for Weblogic 12c.
        weblogic-maven-plugin was how things were done (and was much cleaner)
        but at the time of this work around, it doesn't appear to support Weblogic 12c.

        If in the future, weblogic-maven-plugin or some other plugin become known,
        it should replace both parts of the work around.
     -->
    <!-- START OF WORK AROUND part 1-->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>set-main-artifact</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <source>
              project.artifact.setFile(new File(project.build.directory+'/'+project.artifactId+'-'+project.version+'.war'))
            </source>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <property name="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                        <property name="maven.runtime.classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                        <property name="maven.test.classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath" />
                        <property name="maven.plugin.classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                        <ant antfile="src/main/ant/build.xml" target="all" />
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
                <version>1.0b2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
                <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
                <version>${weblogic.version}</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${bea.lib}/weblogic.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <!-- END OF WORK AROUND part 1 -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <!-- START OF WORK AROUND part 2 -->
            <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>default-war</id>
                      <phase>none</phase>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
              <!-- END OF WORK AROUND part 2 -->
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

*build.xml*

```
<project name="build-webservice" default="all">

    <target name="all" depends="build.webService" />

    <path id="maven_plugin_classpath">
        <pathelement path="${maven.plugin.classpath}" />
    </path>

    <path id="maven_runtime_classpath">
        <pathelement path="${maven.compile.classpath}" />
        <pathelement path="${maven.runtime.classpath}" />
        <pathelement path="${maven.plugin.classpath}" />
        <pathelement path="${weblogic.jar}" />
    </path>

    <taskdef name="jwsc"
             classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask"
             classpath="${weblogic.jar}"
             classpathref="maven_plugin_classpath"
    />

    <target name="build.webService" description="Compile the web services if not up2date">
        <!--
            Eclipse compiles and places classes into target/classes when the workspace is building.
            If this folder exists when jwsc runs, then any classes that are already compiled will NOT
            be included in the final WAR file.  Thus, this directory is removed prior to created the
            webServices WAR fie.
        -->
        <delete dir="target/classes" />
        <jwsc srcdir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"
              destDir="target"
              classpathref="maven_runtime_classpath"
              keepGenerated="yes"
              applicationxml="${project.build.directory}/application.xml"
              fork="true"
              memorymaximumsize="256m"
              verbose="true"
              debug="on"
        >
            <module contextPath="ws" name="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}">
                <jwsfileset srcdir=".">
                   <include name="**/*.java" />
                   <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
                 </jwsfileset>
            </module>
        </jwsc>    
    </target>    
</project>
```

**Overall description:**

1. War plugin execution is overwritten so that it isn't run
2. The compiling and packaging is handled in ant by JwscTask
3. gmaven plugin is used inform maven that it should use the ant generated war as the artifact

**Notes:**

- Alternatives for gmaven were `attachartifact` ant task and `build-helper-maven-plugin` as specified in [How to register a custom built jar file as maven main artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449216/how-to-register-a-custom-built-jar-file-as-maven-main-artifact), but neither worked.  Both resulted in `An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact.`