# Manually attach main artifact if built by maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am having problems building a maven project. I have a requirement to produce *deterministic* jar files, which must be binary-consistent across different builds and versions, in case there are no source code changes in between these builds. For the purpose, I have used [this article](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2013/08/08/how-to-create-a-deterministic-jar/) for guidance.

I have successfully managed to build my jars and they are consistent up to my requirements. Here is my configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>step-1-remove-timestamp</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <touch datetime="01/01/2015 00:10:00 am">
              <fileset dir="target/classes"/>
              <fileset dir="src"/>
            </touch>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>step-3-rename-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-deterministic.zip"
                  tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>step-2-make-assembly</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

In the above code I build and package the jar as a zip, then copy the zip over the expected jar artifact.
The problem with the above, is that maven still executes the `maven-jar-plugin`, so the manually assembled jar is overwritten by the one of the `maven-jar-plugin`. I do not want to use this jar, since it is not consistent with my requirements.

So, I have disabled the `maven-jar-plugin` execution, by explicitly setting it to run for an invalid phase, like below: (saw that from [other posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101750/disable-the-execution-default-jar))

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>never</phase>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>unwanted</finalName>
          <classifier>unwanted</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Everything seems fine, until I discovered my main jar artifact is never installed in the `.m2` directory. To correct this, I also added the `maven-helper-plugin` so that I manually attach any artifacts I produce from the assembler plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-instrumented-jar</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
              <type>jar</type>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This leads to an error I am unable to solve:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:attach-artifact (attach-instrumented-jar) on project my-project: Execution attach-instrumented-jar of goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:attach-artifact failed: For artifact {full-name-of-my-project.jar}: **An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact.** -> [Help 1]

Is there a way to overcome this issue? I've checked for solutions, and most recommend using classifiers, but I want to install the main artifact as would the `maven-jar-plugin`. Other software we are developing will require the standard jar dependency, and we want to avoid complicating our setup by introducing classifiers unreasonably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more trial and failures I happened to come with a working solution. 
I am posting it here with the hopes to either be useful, or to have any issues with pointed to me, as I am not really confident if this is a reliable approach.

So, the error I received

> An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact.

meant to me that I cannot manually install "again" the main artifact. Since that artifact is not produced anymore by the `maven-jar-plugin`, it never gets scheduled for installation even if the file is present (the antrun copy task produces a jar with the same name).

Surprisingly, it needed a few little tricks to make this work again:

1. Re-enabled the `maven-jar-plugin` as it should be:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>default-jar</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   This will produce the standard jar on the `package` phase, and most importantly, makes maven aware for it to be installed during the `install` phase.
2. Tweak the `maven-antrun-plugin` copy tasks to **overwrite** the already produced jar with the deterministic zip. The setup is nearly identical as in my question, so I am only adding the differences:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>...</execution>
       <execution>
         <id>step-3-rename-assembly-and-sources</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <configuration>
           <target>
             <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-deterministic.zip"
                   tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                   overwrite="true"/>
           </target>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
         . . .
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   The copy operation now has `overwrite="true"` specified. Originally, the copy operation seemed to ignore files in the destination if they already exist, and what happened is that the `maven-jar-plugin` had already produced the default jar artifact when the copying occured. With this option set, the `maven-antrun-plugin` now overrides the former jar with the deterministic one, and the latter becomes a subject of the maven `install` phase.
3. Removed the setup from the build-helper-maven-plugin, so that the main jar artifact is not copied a second time:

```
            <artifact>
              <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
              <type>jar</type>
            </artifact>
```

That's it, the correct jar is installed in the `.m2` dir.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have a plugin to create and attach main artifact for you, there is a more generic solution with Groovy Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-main-artifact</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    project.artifact.setFile(new File(project.build.directory, project.build.finalName + ".zip"))
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Inspired by post https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513690/2053580 many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314907/lukasz-guminski

Comment: I have tried it, but it completely messed up the POM - removed about half of it for no reason. Including some properties.